# Phpstorm not starting after memory dump error

Tags: phpstorm

I got an error message that not enough memory while pushing code and then I pressed the "Shutdown" button on that error and since that popup phpstorm does not start. Double clicking on the icon does nothing. Task Manager shows no phpstorm process running.

I uninstalled, restarted the pc and reinstalled, still the same problem. I have no idea what is going on here. Every other application on my system is working as it should.

I got an error similar to this:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Most probably the issue is that JVM can't allocate the requested heap on start. Oracle JVM requires a single chunk of continuous memory (more or less equal to the sum of Xmx and XX:MaxPermSize parameters values) to initialize. On Windows systems 32-bit java can only allocate up to 2 Gb. And any libraries that inject themselves into process memory will reduce this solid block. So it seems that Xmx value you have set is just too much for 32-bit JVM. Please try reducing it to 1024m or 750m, for example - does it work? You need changing PhpStorm.exe.vmoptions file accordingly

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was updating the phpstorm.exe.vmoptions file in the C:\Users\.PhpStorm2016.3 directory.

I changed the Xmx value back to 1024. My errors occurred when I made it 2048 but when I changed it back, PHPStorm worked again. This is for my 32-bit copy.

Answer (score 1):

There was some unknown issue with Java on the system so I downloaded the Dev Kit from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) after uninstalling phpstorm, and then installed phpstorm and the 64-bit version works as it should.

Comment: For me, simply uninstalling Java and installing the latest version fixed it.  This was for my 32-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was updating the phpstorm.exe.vmoptions file, located in the C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 10.0.4\bin folder.

My errors occurred just after I changed the Xmx value from 1024 to 2048. I couldn't make the program run anymore, even after restarting the PC.
Then I changed the Xmx value back to 1024 and restarted the PC. After that, PHPStorm worked again.

Answer (score 0):

for me deleting the directory

```
C:\Users\.PhpStorm2016.3
```

Worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PhpStorm2017.3 and to make it work, I had to delete the folder **.IntelliJIdea2017.3** from the following location:

`C:\Users\admin\.IntelliJIdea2017.3`

For your case, you will have to dig in to the correct folder i.e. the folder "admin" above could be a different folder in your case, so I highly recommend you check it or you may not find the **.IntelliJIdea2017.3** folder in it.